# CSS "absolute" not staying in one place

Tags: css, css-position

I have the following css for a ribbon that I have hanging in a certain part of my website http://www.tonypalazzo.com .

```
.ribbon {
    float:left;
    padding:5px 0 0 0;
    margin:0;
    width:217px;
    position:absolute;
    left: 965px;
    top: 67px;
    z-index: 999999;
}
```

It appears in different horizontal positions when viewed in different sized monitors or even when I zoom in and out in Chrome (and a completely random spot in the design view of Dreamweaver).  It maintains proper vertical (top) positioning, but looks like it always wants to stay 965px away from the left.  This makes it appear in a completely different spot when viewed in different resolutions.

With "relative" position it won't overlay the other div boxes I need it to overlay.  Any help on how I can get this div to sit in the foreground of (overlay) other div's while maintaining the same left/top values relative to where my social media icons sit (see website)?

I've read other posts about this telling me to put it in my "parent" div.  I believe it sits within that if my "block_header" is the parent.  Here is a quick summary of the html (ignore the .'s I put them there just to make sure the code shows:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="block_header">
            <div class="logo"></div>
            <div class="social"></div>
            <div class="ribbon">
                <a href="portfolio.html"><img src="images/portf.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/portf1.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/portf.png'"/></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hi user, welcome to SO!  Just so you know, there's a button that looks like curly braces in the post editor which will let you "show" the code :)

Comment: Also, I'd advise closing all the `<div>` tags, even if it's just an example.

Comment: Um, you have `left: 965px;` ... it's *supposed* to "always wants to stay 965px away from the left." Have you considered `position: fixed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ribbon is staying 965 pixels from the left edge of the screen, just like it's supposed to. If you want it to be positioned relative to it's parent, add the style `position: relative` to the parent. In this instance, you should add it to `.block_header`, then reposition the ribbon.

Comment: Wow that was an easy fix.  Worked like a charm.  Thanks Codemonkey!